# Insert a book object into array of books

Tags: javascript

I am doing a task and I have to add a book into array of books. But instead of getting an array of books, I am getting an empty array.

```
class BookList{
  constructor(){
    this.books = []
  }

  add(book){
    this.books.push(book)
  }
}

class Book{
  constructor(title, genre, author, read){
      this.title = title || "No Title"
      this.genre = genre || "No Genre"
      this.author = author || "No Author"
      this.read = read || false
      this.readDate = new Date(Date.now())
  }
}

let book1 = new Book('Title')

new BookList().add(book1)

let blist = new BookList()

console.log(blist)
```

Comment: You construct two separate booklists, why do you expect the second to have the books?

Comment: You are creating two new `BookList` objects. They will not both have the same books.

Comment: Add `blist.add(book1)`; remove `new BookList().add(book1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have created a new BookList(), but havent stored it:
`new BookList().add(book1)`

If you assign it to a variable, it will work:

```
let book1 = new Book('Title')


let blist = new BookList();

blist.add(book1)

console.log(blist)
```